# "Unable to load theme by specified key: '6

Tags: magento2, error, theme, magento2.1.6

Im getting errors after I done a fresh install to magento 2.1.6 and relinked to old DB.
Now when I select certain items in the menu it will throw this error.
I went to DB and changed the theme ID over but then it goes from Key 6 to Key 4.

What can i do to fix this problem

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
a:4:{i:0;s:42:"Unable to load theme by specified key: '6'";i:1;s:9519:"

#0 /home/www/public_html/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/View/Design.php(148): 
Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\FlyweightFactory->create('6', 'frontend')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess there are some problems in your theme, add your theme table screen shot for check theme issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See if you have saved the theme in products or categories.
In product attribute group 'Schedule Design Update',
attribute New Theme, attribute code `custom_design`.
Also check categories attribute 'Custom Design', attribute code `custom_design`.

You need to update the products and categories data for this attribute in database.

```
`SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = "custom_design";`
```

There are 2 entries, 1 from product and 1 from category.

```
`SELECT * from catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = product custom design attribute id ;`

`SELECT * from catalog_category_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = category custom design attribute id ;`
```

Most likely you didn't set on purpose the Schedule Design on products.
You can delete the entries in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` on **attribute id custom_layout**.

The same to `catalog_category_entity_varchar`.
Or update with empty string/null in these 2 tables. Or set the new theme id, if you set those values on purpose.

Usually the theme id is in products or categories because product imports or other mass action.

Last, reindex all and flush cache.

Also, widgets can have the theme id set.
`SELECT theme_id FROM widget_instance;`
Cms pages:
SELECT `custom_theme` FROM `cms_page`;

Check 'design_*' tables too.

An extra thing to do would be to dump the structure of the database and search on word 'theme'.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to so quickly.
I have searched the DB with your mentioned comment but I am not very sure if I found the right tables.
Do I need to update these rows?
See my original post for the screenshot

Comment: Actually, I just fixed it up but now some products are showing normally and others are just displaying RTL because I assigned id 6 to the RTL theme so the error disappeared.
How can I fix this up now any tips?

Comment: `SELECT * from catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = 100;`

Comment: `SELECT * from catalog_category_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = 60;` These 2 queries will display the products with theme id in custom_layout field/attribute. If you delete those rows or update them with the correct theme_id, it's up to you.

Comment: so where would I need to update them to the new theme id?
sorry still a big noob with sql

Comment: see in the screenshot I posted up where would i update it?

Comment: This is the comment. I'll write the DELETE MySQL query. You don't need to update/delete rows in `eav_attribute` table. But please note to take responsibility when you run it on your server. `DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar  WHERE attribute_id = 60 `;

Comment: Run the delete command if you want the theme_id out from products. If you just want to change the old theme_id with the new one you can run update instead. `UPDATE catalog_product_entity_varchar SET value="CORRECT_THEME_ID" WHERE attribute_id = 60 and value > 0`. Please replace CORRECT_THEME_ID with the theme id you want. Run indexer and cache flush.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/295853/57334

Answer (score 0):

First, check the theme ID in the core config table. As mentioned in the screenshot.

Run basic commands like.

```
rm -r pub/static/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/cache/* var/di var/generation
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

If still error is persisting, Then
Update category and product theme section because category and products are attached to the theme that is already moved.

[image]