# Magento 2.3.3 - How to solve Unable to load theme by specified key

Tags: theme, magento2.3.3, magento1.9.2.3

Front End :

[image]

Note : theme 327k is my magento 1.9 theme

Back End :

[image]

How to solve the theme error after migrate m1 to m2

Comment: Please run this **SELECT *  FROM `theme` WHERE `theme_path` LIKE '%327k%'** in your DB

Comment: @KishanSavaliya above sql command  return empty table. https://snipboard.io/cEr4qu.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run below 4 QUERIES one by one in database.

> DELETE FROM theme WHERE `theme_path` LIKE '%327k%';

- You do not have `theme_path` like 327k in `theme` table so you do not need to run first command.

> UPDATE `cms_page` SET `custom_theme` = NULL;
>
> TRUNCATE TABLE `design_change`;
>
> DELETE FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `value` LIKE '%327k%';

After running this QUERIES in DB please run below commands once

```
rm -rf generated/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/page_cache/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Note : remove values from the table *design_change*

Hope this will help you!

Comment: All of the sql command return 0 rows affected and run below QUERIES no luck, still same error.

Comment: Can you please check you have any directory in your **app/design/frontend** ?

Comment: Magento folder available  inside the location of app/design/frontend.

Comment: Inside the app/design/frontend/Magento folder looking empty.

Comment: Did you run CLI commands ?

Comment: Yes, https://snipboard.io/wM3g57.jpg  i run all the commands rm -rf generated/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/page_cache/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: Can you please run this once ? **SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE core_config_data.path = 'design/theme/theme_id'** in your DB

Comment: And if possible give me that screenshot. If you will get any results there then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101111/discussion-between-zus-and-kishan-savaliya).

Comment: FYI https://snipboard.io/ZBcek3.jpg

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101111/discussion-between-zus-and-kishan-savaliya

Comment: matching with database https://drive.google.com/file/d/10BEDe40J4-0_8a78miWZmhVJK8KM9Yp8/view

Comment: @zus, I've updated my answer, Please run all QUERIES again in your DB. Hope then you will not get this error again.

Comment: Great help by Kishan Savaliya

Comment: Happy to help you. :)

Comment: Hello Kishan, After followed all your steps i am getting error during running upgrade command https://justpaste.it/4z0xv

Comment: @zus, that is different error, you have some duplicate entry in product URL keys, please identify that and remove duplicate entry then you can run command without any errors or just try to disable sample data modules there

Comment: But the error table not available in my  DB https://snipboard.io/tsqZSB.jpg

Comment: Post -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/314448/57334

Answer (score 0):

simply find this record `theme327k` and delete from your database, and run

`bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

just search whole database wildcard, in phpmyadmin or `mysqldump` and `grep` for value, also check if your theme is not defined in `composer.json`

Comment: FYI there is no record found based on theme327k

Comment: SELECT * FROM theme WHERE theme_path LIKE '%327k%'        return 0 rows affected notification.

Comment: Out of memory (allocated 6291456) (tried to allocate 7083982376866503816 bytes) in C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Relations\Runtime.php on line 38  how to solve this error?

Comment: @zus see updated

Comment: Searched entire database https://drive.google.com/file/d/10BEDe40J4-0_8a78miWZmhVJK8KM9Yp8/view

Comment: theme value must be somewhere in database or composer.json

Comment: https://snipboard.io/ZBcek3.jpg

Comment: https://snipboard.io/PnF9TX.jpg

Comment: then you have cache issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101113/discussion-between-zus-and-magenx).

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101113/discussion-between-zus-and-magenx

Comment: php bin/magento cache:clean, 
php bin/magento cache:flush run both of the commands

Comment: theme327k matching in database https://snipboard.io/IjKtSz.jpg

Comment: 36 matches in cms_block,,
22 matches in cms_page,,
1 match in core_config_data,,
1 match in customer_visitor,,
2 matches in design_change